# populating html with javascript array

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to populate html select with javascript array, can you guys help me make this one work below are my codes

external javascript (I have found this code somewhere in the internet)

```
function setRuleName() 
{   var myCars=new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");

        var sel = document.getElementById("dropping") // find the drop down
        for (var i in myCars) 
        { // loop through all elements
            var opt = document.createElement("option"); // Create the new element
            opt.value = title[i]; // set the value
            opt.text = title[i]; // set the text
            sel.appendChild(opt); // add it to the select
        }

}
```

html code

```
<Select  onclick="setRuleName();" id="dropping" >

</Select>
```

Comment: should be `myCars[i]` not `title[i]`

Comment: already tried changing it to myCars ash still not working

Comment: You shouldn't call that function `onclick`, or it will append the `option`s every time you click.

Comment: ashley your are alway helpful and alway hitting it up thanks very cheers!

Comment: guys anyone onclick is working but onload is not any idea? thanks.

Comment: just to lazy guys i've made it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where your `title` attribute came from, but when looping an array, use a standard `for`, not a `for in`

```
for (var i = 0; i < myCars.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement("option"); // Create the new element
    opt.value = myCars[i]; // set the value
    opt.text = myCars[i]; // set the text
    sel.appendChild(opt); // add it to the select
}
```

Comment: yeah admitted it title is wrong, but bro it is still no working, just to add i have two external script wouldn't it making the problem thanks

Comment: no errors in the console and weird i remove the external file where it is located i transferred the code in the other external script and now all the scripts are not working.

Comment: Sounds like the problems are in the other script.

Comment: to update you up, it is already running, the problem now is that im using a onclick event so every time i click the items are added in my drop down list what event must i use so when it loaded all the files are loaded also thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative ways to write this code.**

```
function setRuleName(){

 var myCars=["Saab","Volvo","BMW"],
     sel=document.getElementById("dropping");

 for(var a=0,tit;tit=myCars[a];++a){
  var opt=document.createElement("option");
  opt.value=opt.textContent=tit;
  sel.appendChild(opt);
 }

}
```

**For internal use (NO POST)**

```
function setRuleName(){
 document.getElementById("dropping").innerHTML='<option>'+
 ["Saab","Volvo","BMW"].join('</option><option>')+
 '</option>';
}
```

to access the value :

```
console.log(document.getElementById("dropping").selected.textContent);
```